# How to test a children text component with Jest & Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, enzyme

I'm writing the test suite of my React Native application and I was wondering how to test the shallow rendering of a React Native child component with Jest & Enzyme.

```
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'
import toJson from 'enzyme-to-json'
import React from 'react'

import NextButton from './NextButton'

describe('NextButton component', () => {
  describe('Rendering', () => {
    let onPress, text, wrapper

    beforeEach(() => {
      onPress = jest.fn()
      text = 'Test button'
      wrapper = shallow(<NextButton onPress={onPress}>{text}</NextButton>)
    })

    test('should render NextButton correctly', () => {
      expect(toJson(wrapper)).toMatchSnapshot()
    })

    test('should have text rendered as a child', () => {
      expect(toJson(wrapper.prop('children'))).toEqual(text)
    })
  })
})
```

The previous code gives this error, Jest doesn't find the `children` prop.

```
Expected: "Test button"
Received: undefined
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you just need to test the `text` of your component (and not its props), try with:

`expect(wrapper.text()).toEqual(text);`

Comment: How about expect(wrapper.children()).toEqual(text)? Maybe for a more complex use case... wrapper.text() seems neat!